# Strange behavior where UDPClient (listener) wont work if instantiated before UDPClient (sender)

Tags: c#, sockets, garbage-collection, udp, udpclient

I made an app that sends a UDP message to a another application and then listens for a UDP message response. However, the weirdest thing I've ever seen is happening. I eventually found that it is the order of my code that seems to be the problem, but I'm not sure why that is. I've narrowed my code after many hours to these lines:

Not Working Code:

```
    UDPSender sender = new UDPSender(destinationIP, portDest, sourceIP, portSource, AgentTypeEnum.User, this);
    listener = new UDPListener(sourceIP, portSource, AgentTypeEnum.User, this);
    listener.StartListener();
    sender.SendUDPOnce(new BytesAndRequestType(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asciiChars), null), successFlag);
```

Working Code:

```
    listener = new UDPListener(sourceIP, portSource, AgentTypeEnum.User, this);
    listener.StartListener();
    UDPSender sender = new UDPSender(destinationIP, portDest, sourceIP, portSource, AgentTypeEnum.User, this);
    sender.SendUDPOnce(new BytesAndRequestType(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(asciiChars), null), successFlag);
```

Here is my code for the specifics of the UDPSender and UDPListener. Basically all it does is wrap up the UDPClient and does specific listening and sending of UDP packets to and from destinations.

UDPSender:

```
namespace Agent
{
    public class UDPSender
    {
        private IPAddress destIpAddress;
        private IPAddress sourceIPAddress;
        private int destPortNumber;
        private int sourcePortNumber;
        private byte[] header;         // first part of message byte array
        private SequenceMapSelector mapper = SequenceMapSelector.Instance;
        private Timer udpSendTimer;
        IPEndPoint destinationEP;
        IPEndPoint sourceEP;

        UdpClient sender;

        public UDPSender(string destIpAddress, int destPortNumber, string sourceIPAddress, int sourcePortNumber, AgentTypeEnum mt, ParentAgent pa)
        {
            this.destIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(destIpAddress);
            this.sourceIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(sourceIPAddress);
            header = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Apple!");
            // This could have been done with bit shifts and masking
            // header[0] = (byte)(0x424f4f425321 >> 40 & 0xFF);
            // header[1] = (byte)(0x424f4f425321 >> 32 & 0xFF);
            // header[2] = (byte)(0x424f4f425321 >> 24 & 0xFF);
            // header[3] = (byte)(0x424f4f425321 >> 16 & 0xFF);
            // header[4] = (byte)(0x424f4f425321 >> 8 & 0xFF);
            // header[5] = (byte)(0x424f4f425321 & 0xFF);
            // Or this as well
            // header[0] = (byte)((0x424f4f425321 & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
            // header[1] = (byte)((0x424f4f425321 << 8 & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
            // header[2] = (byte)((0x424f4f425321 << 16 & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
            // header[3] = (byte)((0x424f4f425321 << 24 & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
            // header[4] = (byte)((0x424f4f425321 << 32 & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
            // header[5] = (byte)((0x424f4f425321 << 40 & 0xFF0000000000) >> 40);
            this.destPortNumber = destPortNumber;
            this.sourcePortNumber= sourcePortNumber;
            sourceEP = new IPEndPoint(this.sourceIPAddress, sourcePortNumber);

            sender = new UdpClient
            {
                ExclusiveAddressUse = false
            };
            sender.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            sender.Client.Bind(sourceEP);
            mapper.CreateSystemGroup(this.destIpAddress, mt, pa); // must create a system group so that when data comes in we can look up the group
        }

        public byte SendUDPOnce(BytesAndRequestType udpDataAndCommandUsed, bool successFlag) // i think i can just return void
        {
            byte[] sendbuf = new byte[3 + header.Length + udpDataAndCommandUsed.ASCII_Bytes.Length]; // [0] = lastOctet [1] = sequenceNum;

            byte sequenceNum = BuildByteMessage(header, udpDataAndCommandUsed.ASCII_Bytes, sendbuf, (RequestTypeEnum?)udpDataAndCommandUsed.requestType, successFlag); // I should refactor this to just take a CommandParameters.BytesAndRequestEnum
            destinationEP = new IPEndPoint(destIpAddress, destPortNumber);
            sender.Send(sendbuf, sendbuf.Length, destinationEP);
            // Console.WriteLine("Sender: Message sent to the broadcast address: " + toIpAddress + Environment.NewLine + "Sender: contents (first byte is IP_Octet, second is sequenceNumber): " + string.Join(",", sendbuf));
            return sequenceNum;
        }

        public void SendUDPContinuously(BytesAndRequestType udpDataAndCommandUsed, bool successFlag, int delayMiliseconds)
        {
            udpSendTimer = new Timer(sate => SendUDPOnce(udpDataAndCommandUsed, successFlag), null, 0, delayMiliseconds);
        }

        public void StopUDPContinuousSend()
        {
            mapper.DumpDataToFile(destIpAddress);
            udpSendTimer.Dispose();
        }

        private byte BuildByteMessage(byte[] header, byte[] parameterCommand, byte[] destination, RequestTypeEnum? commandEnum, bool successFlag)
        {
            byte sequenceNum = mapper.CreateNextSequenceByte(destIpAddress, commandEnum);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(header, 0, destination, 0, header.Length);
            destination[header.Length] = (byte)(commandEnum == null ? RequestTypeEnum.ERROR : commandEnum);
            destination[header.Length+1] = sequenceNum;
            destination[header.Length + 2] = (byte)(successFlag ? 1: 0);
            // add header to parameterCommand
            Buffer.BlockCopy(parameterCommand, 0, destination, header.Length + 3, parameterCommand.Length);
            return sequenceNum;
        }
    }
}
```

UDPListener:

```
namespace Agent
{
    // in this context, the source is the machine that this code is running on. and the destination is the IP address of the agent machine.
    public class UDPListener
    {
        IPAddress ipAddressSource;
        int listenPort;
        private SequenceMapSelector sequenceMap = SequenceMapSelector.Instance;
        UdpClient listener;
        IPEndPoint endPoint;
        IPEndPoint sendersEndPoint;
        AgentTypeEnum agentTypeOfCurrentMachine;
        ParentAgent pa;

        public UDPListener(string ipAddressOfSource, int portSource, AgentTypeEnum agentTypeOfCurrentMachine, ParentAgent pa)
        {
            this.agentTypeOfCurrentMachine = agentTypeOfCurrentMachine;
            ipAddressSource = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressOfSource); // need to listen to the IP address this UDP message is coming FROM
            listenPort = portSource;   // need to listen to the the port that the UDP message was sent TO
            this.pa = pa;
        }

        public void StartListener()
        {
            listener = new UdpClient
            {
                ExclusiveAddressUse = false
            };

            listener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            endPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddressSource, listenPort); //new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort); this might allow me not to know the IP of this local device!
            listener.Client.Bind(endPoint);

            try
            {
                listener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(Receive), null);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ErrorLogger.WriteExceptionToLog(e);
                listener.Close();
            }
            finally
            {

            }
        }

        private void Receive(IAsyncResult res)
        {
            byte[] bytes = listener.EndReceive(res, ref sendersEndPoint);
            listener.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(Receive), null);
            if (sequenceMap.FindSystemGroup(sendersEndPoint.Address) == null)
            {
                // if there was no system group for this type of agent, then add a system group for it.
                // are both the AgentType and requestType in bytes[6]??? this seems incorrect
                sequenceMap.CreateSystemGroup(sendersEndPoint.Address, agentTypeOfCurrentMachine, pa); // in this case we don't want (AgentTypeEnum)bytes[6] since this would give us the agent type of the sender machine
                sequenceMap.CreateNextSequenceByte(sendersEndPoint.Address, (RequestTypeEnum)bytes[6]); // in this case we don't want (RequestTypeEnum)bytes[6] since this would give us the agent type of the sender machine
            }
            sequenceMap.AddDataToLookup(sendersEndPoint.Address, sendersEndPoint.Port, bytes[7], bytes);
            Console.WriteLine("Received" + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: both UDPClients (sender and listener) are bound to the same IP, but different port numbers. No exceptions are thrown. My theory is that garbage collection might be coming into play?

The answer I'm looking for is to explain why the UDPListener never receives any UDP messages when my UDPSender is instantiated first, but if I do it in reverse order it works fine.

Comment: You always start the Server (listener) before the client.

Comment: @jdweng Why does this matter? shouldn't I be able to use this in a peer to peer fashion? that is the goal for the app I am writing

Comment: Also, I'm always "starting" the listener before the client. But I am "instantiating" the sender first. but this should not matter

Comment: A peer to peer still has on end of TCP/UDP connection a server and other end listener.  With UDP there are three different types 1) Normal which is the same as TCP except TCP ACKs every message 2) Broadcast Multicast  IP 124-139 3) Broadcast non Multicast.  I do not see in your code you are specifying Broadcast so I think it is defaulting to TYPE 1 which means the server must start before the client.